# Unwrapping Optionals (Swift Playground)

Tags: swift, conditional-statements, option-type, forced-unwrapping

Simple question for you folks about unwrapping optionals.

I've read and seen the multiple examples of unwrapping like the following

```
var strArray: [String]?
strArray = ["John", "Stacy", "Stephanie" ]

if let forSureNames = strArray{
   for name in forSureNames{
      print("\(name)")
   }
} else{
    print("Failed unwrapping")
}
```

However, My question is for `if let forSureNames = strArray{`...

When typing syntax similar to C++ (and from some swift examples), adding parenthesis

```
if (let forSureNames = strArray){
```

Gives the error codes:

```
'()' is not convertible to 'Bool'

error: MyPlayground.playground:13:4: error: expected expression in list of expressions
if(let forSureName = strArrays){
   ^
error: MyPlayground.playground:13:4: error: expected '{' after 'if' condition
if(let forSureName = strArrays){
   ^
```

Can anyone help explain the difference?

***Edit***
First time I asked a question on Stack overflow and feedback is awesome. I was trying to use a similar coding style to C++ due to my familiarity for an easy transition. However, you guys made it clear that it’s an incorrect approach. Thank you for a new and technical perspective towards unwrapping. Cheers!

Comment: Assignment does not equal Boolean expression in swift. `let forSureNames = strArray` does not evaluate to true or false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, `()` can be used to surround an expression and it will have no effect on the evaluation of that expression, and you are asking "why can't I do the same to `let forSureNames = strArray`?" Right?

This is because `let forSureNames = strArray` is not an expression. You are parsing this statement wrong. The word `let` is part of the `if let` statement.

You are confusing `if let` statements with C-style if statements, where after the `if`, there is always an expression that evaluates to `Bool`. `if let` simply does not work like that. It takes the form:

```
if let <identifier> = <expression> { }
```

where `expression` must evaluate to an optional type. So putting `()` around `let <identifier> = <expression>` makes little sense. You could put `()` around `strArray` because *that* is an expression, but I don't see the point of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (let forSureNames = strArray) {
```

... this is trying to use optional binding. Optional binding allows you to safely unwrap some optional constant/variable which can be `nil`. If this value is assigned, it satisfies the `if` statement with this unwrapped (non-optional) constant/variable.

But, it doesn't work with parentheses, since values coming from parentheses have to be of type `Bool`. An optional binding doesn't return a `Bool` value directly, it just attempts to assign the constant/variable and *implicitly* returns a boolean based on whether the assignment occurred.

```
if (true) {...} // works
if (let value = optional) {...} // doesn't work
```

So, you have to remove these parentheses

```
if let forSureNames = strArray {...}
```

Unlike other languages, conditions in Swift don't have to be inside parentheses and it is recommended not to use them if they aren't required.

Answer (score 0):

Swift is vastly different from C++, so you shouldn't be surprised that C++ syntax doesn't work in Swift.

There are two type of `if` statements in Swift: the type that takes an expression (`if foo.bar`), and the type that does pattern matching (`if let foo = bar`, `if case .some(let foo) = bar`, etc).

Because Swift supports parenthesized expressions, `if foo.bar` works the same as `if (foo.bar)`: in the first case, the condition is `foo.bar`, and in the second case, the condition is `(foo.bar)`. In other words, the parentheses here are part of the condition expression, not part of the `if` statement. This contrasts with C++, where the parentheses are part of the `if` statement. In both cases, however, you can add as many parentheses as you want: `if (((((((((foo.bar)))))))))`, though silly, is superficially valid in both languages.

Recall that you can wrap arbitrary expressions in parentheses, but you can't just wrap anything in parentheses. You wouldn't write `(if foo.bar)` in Swift or C++, because you know that `if` isn't an expression. Then, the same applies to `let foo = bar`. It's not an expression either, so you can't wrap it in parentheses. `if let foo = bar` is fine, but `if (let foo = bar)` isn't.

C++ supports a similar syntax in some cases:

```
if (auto foo = make_unique<int>(3)) { ... } else { ... }
```

This syntax declares `foo` and tests it (using its `operator bool()`), and then branches the program appropriately. Since the condition is a declaration statement, not an expression, it can't be wrapped in more parentheses either: `if ((auto foo = make_unique<int>(3)))` is a compile-time error, just like `if (let foo = bar)` in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone help explain the difference?

The difference is that Swift is not C++. Although they are similar in many ways, they have different grammars. The grammar defines (in part) the language's syntax.

In C++, an `if` statement is part of [the *selection-statement* production](http://www.nongnu.org/hcb/#selection-statement) in the grammar:

> *selection-statement:*
>
> > `if` `(` *condition* `)` *statement*
> >
> > `if` `(` *condition* `)` *statement* `else` *statement*
> >
> > `switch` `(` *condition* `)` *statement*

So the parentheses around the condition of the `if` statement are part of the `if` statement, and **not** part of the condition.

In Swift, an `if` statement is the only production of [the *if-statement* production](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html#grammar_if-statement) in the grammar:

> *if-statement* → `if` condition-list code-block else-clause<sub>opt</sub>

Note that there are no parentheses directly in the *if-statement*'s production. So if there are to be parentheses, they must be part of the *condition-list* production. [Here's how *condition-list* is defined](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html#grammar_condition-list):

> *condition-list* → condition | condition `,` condition-list
>
> *condition* → expression | availability-condition | case-condition | optional-binding-condition

So a *condition-list* is one or more *condition*s, separated by commas. If you click through each of the four alternatives in *condition*, you'll find that *availability-condition* must start with the token `#availability`, *case-condition* must start with the token `case`, and *optional-binding-condition* must start with either the token `let` or the token `var`. None of those three productions can start with a parenthesis token.

The only production of *condition* that can start with the token `(` is the *expression* production, and an *expression* production cannot have the token `let` after the token `(`.